Aggregate sum up to a certain column - total cost until today
Suppose you have a list of costs per month, per type.
You can have multiple rows with the same type.
How can you get the "total aggregate cost for each category from January until month X"?
Here is the example of what I am looking for.



Type
Jan
Feb
Mar




A1
1000
1000
1000


A1
2000
2000
2000


A1
5000
5000
5000


A2
300
300
300


A2
0
0
0


B1
100
200
100


B2
0
0
400


B2
250
250
250



should aggregate to:



Type
Jan
Feb
Mar




A1
8000
16000
24000


A2
300
600
900


B1
100
300
400


B2
250
500
1150




First decide which you are using Excel or Googlesheets or Libreoffice-calc

To 'repair' your existing formulas, use =SUMIF($A$3:$A$10,$A33,B$3:B$10) and =B33+SUMIF($A$3:$A$10,$A33,C$3:C$10). Pay attention to where to lock rows and/or columns. A simpler single-formula solution would be =SUMPRODUCT(IF($A$3:$A$10=$A33,$B$3:B$10)).

In Microsoft 365 or Google Sheets try (doesn't work under LibreOffice):
=LET(
    data, A1:M10,
    monthly_data, INDEX(data, 3, 2):INDEX(data, ROWS(data), COLUMNS(data)),
    type, INDEX(data, 3, 1):INDEX(data, ROWS(data), 1),
    sou_type, SORT(UNIQUE(type)),
    total_for_type_month, LAMBDA(sou_type_index, month_index,
        SUM(
            FILTER(
                CHOOSECOLS(monthly_data, SEQUENCE(month_index)),
                type = INDEX(sou_type, sou_type_index)
            )
        )
    ),
    totals, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(sou_type), COLUMNS(monthly_data), total_for_type_month),
    header, CHOOSEROWS(data, 1, 2),
    VSTACK(IF(LEN(header), header, ""), HSTACK(sou_type, totals))
)



Suppose your data range is A1:D11 (A2:A11 types, B1:D1 months, B2:D11 data) and your target range is A13:D17 (A14:A17 types, B13:D13 months, B14:D17 results).
Set B14 to:
=SUMIF($A$3:$A$10,$A14,B$3:B$10)

and copy down to D14. Note the careful placements of $ to ensure correct absolute/relative references.
Then set C14 to:
=B14+SUMIF($A$3:$A$10,$A14,C$3:C$10)

and copy throughout the rest of the range.
Better, add a 'zero' (blank) column at the start (so that the January results 'add zero'); this way you can copy the same formula for the whole range.

An alternative with QUERY is given below,
Formula in cell A13 is;
=QUERY({A3:A10,BYROW(B3:M10, LAMBDA(row, SCAN(0, row, LAMBDA(µ, x, µ + x))))},"Select Col1, Sum(Col2), Sum(Col3), Sum(Col4), Sum(Col5), Sum(Col6), Sum(Col7), Sum(Col8), Sum(Col9),Sum(Col10), Sum(Col11), Sum(Col12), Sum(Col13) Group By Col1")

.

